# Create a new dict of first n values (and keys) from dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{'my_account': [45010045, 43527907, 45147474, 35108100, 45159973],
 'your_account': [38966628, 28171579, 39573751, 41359842, 42445236],
 'his_account': [44822460, 45010045, 39276850, 39896128, 45265335]
}
```

I want to keep the first 2 elements of every key, so the result would look like:

```
{'my_account': [45010045, 43527907],
 'your_account': [38966628, 28171579],
 'his_account': [44822460, 45010045]
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes -- it should be a pretty straight forward dictionary comprehension with some list slicing... Is there something that you're having trouble with specifically?

Comment: It is easy you can accomplish that by take function like that: take(n, d.iteritems())

Comment: @FadySaad Neither Python 2 nor Python 3 has a built-in function `take`. The easiest way to accompligh this task is with a dictionary comprehension with slicing `{k: v[:2] for k, v in d.items()}`

Comment: @ Patrick Haugh python3 itertools has a take function and here is the link [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I originally tried take function, but it does not work as I use Python 2. Dictionary comprehension with slicing (also suggested by @mgilson) works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @FadySaad `itertools` doesn't provide that function, it's just described there (because its implementation is trivial).  Try `itertools.take` in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using dictionary comprehension

```
my_dict = {'my_account': [45010045, 43527907, 45147474, 35108100, 45159973],
 'your_account': [38966628, 28171579, 39573751, 41359842, 42445236],
 'his_account': [44822460, 45010045, 39276850, 39896128, 45265335]
}

new_dict = {k:v[:2] for k,v in my_dict.items()}
# {'my_account': [45010045, 43527907], 'your_account': [38966628, 28171579], 'his_account': [44822460, 45010045]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just slice-delete the values.

```
for v in D.itervalues():
  del v[2:]
```